# Php user-agent Graceful Degradation

Tags: php, browser

I am looking to detect how modern the user's browser is.  For example Google displays a table based gmail depending on the browser, and a table based layout for Google images also depending on the browser.  http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6557

Google's choice of "modern" browsers is fine with me, but I am unsure how to insure future functionality.  When user agent strings change or a new browser is released it seems the list of user agent strings would have to change.

**Edit :** I ended up using the concept as the mordernizer php server library.  I test for functionality and if the default settings aren't correct I set a cookie and refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [modernizr-server library](https://github.com/jamesgpearce/modernizr-server), which is a port of [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to php, for detecting what modern features a visitor's browser supports. More information is available in the [Modernizr on the server-side](http://tripleodeon.com/2010/10/modernizr-on-the-server-side/) blog post.

[Browser.php](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/) is similar, but detects OS, browser, and version (not whether a particular feature is supported). The [Browser Capabilities Project](http://browsers.garykeith.com/) is another possible option.

Comment: That is a cool idea, but we aren't really targeting specific features and it requires for javascript to be enabled.  Another caveat is that the extra page refresh can't be good for user experience.